# How to keep log INFO into 'logtable' even though exception had occur in Storedprocedures

Tags: oracle

Suppose you are writing a complex stored-procedure with various steps. in each step you are logging some info into local 'logtable' as well.

However, after 6/7th steps some exception had happened and you have to rollback. How can we keep those log info into that 'logtable', even though we are rolling back.

Thanks

Comment: If you are planning to do such kind of logging across your project I would recommend using the following tool. http://log4plsql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an autonomous transaction to commit the logtable writes as they occur:

```
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LogTable...;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

See [Autonomous Transactions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions)